# How to Legally Use Google Imagery and Maps in ArcGIS Desktop and Web Applications?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, google-maps, google-maps-api, arcgis-flex-api

With companies like [Arc2Earth](http://accounts.arc2earth.com/docs/dataservices2) and [Spatial Energy](http://www.spatialenergy.com/programs_ondemand.html) offering solutions to view Google imagery and maps inside ArcGIS for Desktop, there is clearly a legal way to develop a similar product yourself. My question is how can this be accomplished and what licensing is required?

We would like to (legally) view and print Google imagery and maps inside ArcGIS for Desktop, Flex based web mapping applications, and JavaScript web mapping applications. My dream is to somehow provide this as a map service or image service using ArcGIS for Server.

Comment: I got a down vote right away on this... would have liked to know why.

Comment: I suggest you start with [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?csw=1&safe=on) for the licensing details.

Comment: Also, related to the ArcGIS Server aspect of your question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305/consuming-google-maps-as-background-map-through-arcgis-server

Comment: You can purchase the enterprise license from Google http://www.google.ca/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html $10,000 is the base starting point.

Comment: The Google Static Maps API seems like an interesting possibility, an old blog post for a Silverlight app talks about it in some detail [here](http://rexdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/09/use-google-maps-with-arcgis-silverlight.html). Any thoughts?

Comment: At the moment I think your question by asking about ArcGIS for Desktop and Server, is too broad, because licensing models are usually very different for desktop and server products.  I recommend that you edit your question to focus it on ArcGIS for Desktop, and then research/ask about ArcGIS for Server separately.